# Can you change the default save extension for notepad++ based on the user defined language?

Tags: notepad++

I have a user defined language that I use for txt files. When I set the extension to txt in the style pane and open a txt file, everything works fine, the proper words are highlighted and everything.

However, when I use the "Save as" feature, no extension is automatically selected.

Is there a way to make my user defined language automatically save as a txt file?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the extension for any language in the langs.xml file. In windows this is located in AppData/Roaming/Notepad++. Find the tag for your language and change the ext attribute to what you want.

Comment: Tried this. Open a new document. Add some text. Save. Type defaults to "All Types". This makes me sad.

Comment: Under "Default Directory", I had selected "Use new style save dialog (without file extension feature)". Once I unselected this, I got my default extension back. Happy now :).

Comment: Nice. I was having a problem with .yaml files being saved as .yml by default, you can change the ordering in the langs file to change that.

Answer (score 1):

The following was the solution in this case, where I just wanted .txt for plain files:

Go to `Settings` -> `Preferences` -> `Default Directory` -> then uncheck the checkbox (which appears to be checked by default):

> Use new style save dialog (**without file extension feature**)

Yes, they call it a "feature" (apparently they thought an obsolete one!) to use a default extension, and they call the reverse a "new style save dialog" (who would not want that on the surface, a better explorer dialog it seems to mean). I found this thanks to Ishmael's answer in a comment above.

[soapbox] *Let me thank the notepad++ team, but then register my dissatisfaction at such an utterly counter user-friendly of a setting, that this would be a feature turned on by default, and so hard to find. I had to wade through so many answers all across the web which didn't work (changing lang.xml / configuration.xml values manually, etc), this took hours, and in the process I seriously considered a different basic text IDE that would be more user-friendly and make me not want to throw a rock at it. What user wants to save files by default **without** an extension by default / on a regular basis, where the system doesn't know how to recognize it? So why make this the out-of-box feature?* [/soapbox]